# Javascript event to indicate the time validators has changed its valid state

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

[image]

Is there any way to know by javascript that textbox has changed its valid state, in this situation as in the image. If all the validation in a rows is valid, we will hide that row but if any validation in that row is not valid, we will show that row.

What i will do now is to use onblur on each textbox but i doubt that is there is a better way or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a listener to your form using `setInterval`. I have cooked up an basic example of that [@this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/).